# What are the best driver routines in LAPACK for implementing the Moore-Penrose psudo inversion

Tags: lapack, matrix-inverse

I want to solve Y = X * A, for A (where Y is NxO, X is NxI, and A is IxO with  N>>O,I)

I want to use the Moore-Penrose inverse A = inv(transpose(X) * X) * (transpose(X) * Y)

the square matrix:  (transpose(X) * X) is IxI and symmetric and semi-positive definite.

I thought about using DSYSV  which solves A*X=B for X where A is symmetric and positive definite. I could substitute my transpose(X)*X for A, and transpose(X)*Y for B then the solution X will be the coefficient matrix I called A above.

I am wondering if there is a more efficient combination of LAPACK driver routines to carry out this operation?

Answer (score 1):

No, the technical roadmap you considered is wrong. The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is solved from SVD, c.f. [numpy.linalg.pinv — NumPy v1.23 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html): note that `pinv` is a function in both python, matlab and octave.

Here is my attempt:

static int dgepinv(double Ainv[], const unsigned int m, const unsigned int n, const double A[]) {

```
double a[m*n];
memcpy(a, A, m*n*sizeof(double));
unsigned int k = (m<n)? m:n;

double s[k];
memset(s, 0, sizeof(s));
double superb[k];
memset(superb, 0, sizeof(superb));
double u[m*m];
double vt[n*n];

int err = LAPACKE_dgesvd(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'A', 'A', m, n, a,n, s, u,m, vt,n, superb);

if (m>n)
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<n*n; i++)
        vt[i] *= 1/s[i/n];
else
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<m*m; i++)
        u[i] *= 1/s[i%m];

memset(Ainv, 0, n*m*sizeof(double));
for (unsigned int i=0, all=n*m; i<all; i++)
    for (unsigned int j=0; j<k; j++)
        Ainv[i] += vt[j*n+(i/m)] * u[(i%m)*m+j];

return err;
```

}

At least work with the KAT in [dgesvd_example.r](https://github.com/numericalalgorithmsgroup/LAPACK_Examples/blob/master/examples/baseresults/dgesvd_example.r)

Comment: Thank you for the code example.

I just recently learned about using SVD for pseudo-inverse.
If $M = U S V^T$ using Singular-value decomposition,
then $M^{-1} = V S^{-1} U^T$ and since $S$ is a diagonal matrix then inverting it is just taking the reciprocal of each diagonal element. Looking at your code I believe that that is just what you implemented.